# Train/test set split for LSTM with multivariate Time series

Tags: keras, sequence, padding, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to solve time series prediction problem for multivariate data in Python using LSTM approach.

In [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/%23comment-459053) , the author solving problem for time series air pollution prediction. The data looks like this:

```
                    pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain
date
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     0
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2     0
```

As opposed to yearly in the above tutorial, I have a 30-sec time step observations on soccer matches with over 20 features. Where each match with unique ID has different length ranging from 190 to 200.

The author split train/test set by number of days in a year as follow:

```
# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
```

So my train/test set should be by number of matches:
 (matches*len(match))

```
n_train_matches = some k number of matches * len(match)
train = values[:n_train_matches, :]
test = values[n_train_matches:, :]
```

I want to translate this to my problem to make a prediction for each feature as early as time t=2. I.e. 30-sec into a match.

**Question**

Do I need to apply pre-Sequence Padding on each match?

Is there a way of solving the problem without padding?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an LSTM then I believe you are more likely to benefit from that model if you are padding and feeding in multiple 30 second step observations.

If you didn't pad the sequences, and you wanted a prediction at t=2, then you'll only be able to use the very last step-observation.